# Suppress Divide or Mod by zero Compiler Error in C

Tags: c, crash, divide-by-zero

I am writing a C program where I want to trigger an exception such that the program crashes on Windows and invokes the Windows Error Reporting.

I thought, one good way to trigger a crash would be to divide by zero. However, when I try to do that, the compiler wouldn't compile the program and give the error: C2124.

Is there a way that I can force the compiler to compile the program and ignore the above divide by zero statement in the code?

Or should I find another way to crash my program? :)

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    return 1/0;
}
```

Comment: you can use a null pointer access

Comment: Call [`abort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/program/abort)?

Comment: take the input from user so as to bypass compile time check?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`abort`, defined in `<stdlib.h>` is the preferred way to cause abnormal program termination. However, a solution to your specific intent to cause a divide-by-zero is to conceal the divisor from the compiler:

```
volatile int x = 0;
return 1/x;
```

The keyword `volatile` tells the compiler that `x` may be changed in ways unknown to the compiler. This prevents the compiler from knowing that it is zero, so the compiler must generate code to perform the division at run-time in case `x` is changed to something other than zero.

Of course, the behavior of division by zero is not defined, so it is not guaranteed to cause program termination.

Also keep in mind that “If you lie to the compiler, it will get its revenge.” (Henry Spencer).

Comment: `volatile` prevents certain optimizations and is not a good way to suppress warnings.

Comment: @wonder.mice: Does it solve the OP’s request to create a divide-by-zero error during program execution, rather than during compilation, and do you have any alternate solution? Nobody needs an optimization for this program termination, and the fact that this `x`, used solely here, is volatile will not affect optimization of the rest of the program.

Comment: I support use of `abort()` variants, just afraid that `volatile` technique can be used by folks in a different context where it actually matters. Didn't meant to downvote, was accidental click, but when I noticed it was too late, sorry.

Answer (score 3):

`1/0` is evaluated at compile time. The compiler is smart enough to detect that it's not going to work.

I'd do either:

```
int a = 0;
return 1/a;
```

(you may get a warning but that's going to compile)

Or trigger a null pointer access:

```
int *p = NULL;
return *p;
```

Answer (score 2):

It's hard to get a C program to crash in a well-defined way. Really it's a contradiction in terms.

Favourite ways are inducing stack overflows, null pointer dereferences, and divisions by zero. But compilers are getting better at spotting these tricks. Recursions can get unrolled to loops, and since `1/0` is a compile-time evaluable constant expression, and it's behaviour is undefined, a compiler is allowed to fail compilation.

A more reliable way is to use `void abort(void)` from `<stdlib.h>`. That at least is guaranteed by the C standard not to return to the caller:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
int main(int, char **)
{
    abort();
}
```